# Can a trained decision tree always return a prediction for some data input?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

If I have a well trained decision tree, is it likely that there are still some combinations of attributes for which the tree has no prediction? What I mean to say is, is it possible to have a decision tree that responds to all possible combinations of inputs from a dataset that it was not trained on? I am not concerned with the accuracy of the tree, instead I wonder if a good decision tree would be expected to have a prediction for all possible combinations of inputs.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether by "combination of attributes" you are referring to the set of attributes for which values are provided or you mean the combination of particular values (for all attributes). For example, suppose you have attributes A, B, C, and D. And attribute A can have values {A_1, A_2,...,AA_n} (and similarly for attributes B, C, and D).

If by "combinations of attributes", you mean that sometimes values will be provided for all attributes but other times only a subset (e.g., only values for A, C, and D), then it depends on the particular decision tree implementation. For example [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) requires that each sample have values for all of the attributes, whereas [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) does not (i.e., it handles missing attributes).

If by "combinations of attributes" you mean that all attributes are always present but not all combinations of attribute *values* were encountered during training (e.g., there was no training sample with the combination (A_2, B_5, C_1, D_4)), then yes, the trained decision tree should be able to handle those cases. More specifically, the trained tree should be able to classify all combinations of values for the attributes on which it was trained.

If a node corresponding to a particular attribute did not have training samples with a particular value of the attribute, then the prediction is made based on the value of the parent node's attribute (the next node closer to the root). For example, suppose you have a new observation (A_2, B_5, C_1, D_4). You could have a trained tree whose root node branches on attribute C. Based on the given attribute value C=C_1, the tree may then branch on attribute B and based on B=B_5, it may make its prediction. It is possible that there are no training samples with the combination (*, B_5, C_1, *). In that case, the prediction is be based solely on the value C=C_1.

Or maybe there are training examples with C=C_1 and B=B_5 but that combination is already sufficient to make the prediction. In that case, the values of A and D for new observations are irrelevant for this combination of B and C. Since all new observations matching (*, B_5, C_1, *) have the same prediction, it is not necessary that associated values of A and D are also present in the training data.